# Trying to move space-invaders & unable to move in both directions

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

working on a personal project to self develop with c#

i'm currently working on a console app using c# for space invaders - i made the decision to use a 2d array in order to store my game.

my current class for invaders is below, i can "summon" the invaders, move them from left to right, then drop a row and move right to left but they don't iterate back through in the other direction.

```
    public void SummonMovingInvaders(int row, int col, Map[,] spaceInvaders)
    {
        var checkGameOver = new ConsoleInterface();

        while (checkGameOver.GameOverCheck(spaceInvaders) == false)
        {
            row = 1;
            while (spaceInvaders[row, col].Filled == false)
            {
                //Set up original invaders
                for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    spaceInvaders[1, i].Type = CellType.Invader;
                }


                for (row = 1; row < 10; row++)
                {
                    for (col = 0; col < 4; col++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 3; j > 0; j--)
                        {
                            if (j == 0)
                            {
                                spaceInvaders[row, col + j].Type = CellType.Empty;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                spaceInvaders[row, col + j].Type = spaceInvaders[row, col + j - 1].Type;
                            }

                        }
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }

                    //Clear out the row
                    for (int i = 1; i < spaceInvaders.GetLength(1); i++)
                    {
                        spaceInvaders[row, i].Type = CellType.Empty;
                    }

                    row++;

                    for (col = 6; col >= 0; col--)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                        {
                            if (col > 0)
                                spaceInvaders[row, col + j - 1].Type = CellType.Invader;
                            else
                                spaceInvaders[row, col + j].Type = CellType.Invader;

                        }
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
                        {
                            if (col > 1)
                            {
                                spaceInvaders[row, col].Type = CellType.Empty;
                                spaceInvaders[row, col - 2].Type = spaceInvaders[row, col - 1].Type;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    col = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be hard to answer this question without basically debugging your entire program. But no, posting all your source code is probably not the answer. This is hard enough to read and figure out as it is. Your challenge is to reduce and refine this question. Narrow it down some. You might even solve the problem yourself if you do that.

Comment: Thanks - will give it a go and see what happens